# implement a dynamic frontend UI based on roles

Tags: design-patterns, ui

We want to build a new frontend for our existing app with elements shown or hidden based on a users role.

Are there any common patterns for this? I see two ways of doing this.

- The backend sends the user role to the fronted, the frontend knows
  about what roles can see what elements.
- Or the backend knows about the elements in the frontend and gives a
  mapping of what should be shown or hidden.

Are there any preferences, or other ways of going about this? Either way involves coupling of the frontend and backend.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to run the **business logic on a client**. This may be dangerous, but sometimes it's inevitable — people want to have nice dynamic reactive UI. Be aware of the following issues:

1. Some business logic may slip into front-end and stay there. Consequences may range from inconsistent UI to dangerous security holes.
2. Code duplication may cause discrepancy between back-end and front-end. If you are lucky to use same language on both sides, this problem can be *partially* mitigated — still, there will be cases when front-end does not have all required information.
3. This *may* leak security-related implementation details and other users' data. Helping potential attacker is not a good idea.

Sending plain roles/permissions will cause maximum coupling. It makes more sense to send sets of flags that describe availability of operations: "CanEditOrder", "CanDeleteOrder". Just remember that if you're doing any validation on client-side, you have to to repeat it in the back-end.

(As a side note, there is one trick I found when developing CRM/ERP with lots of complex rules. Put a button somewhere, that may be activated by IT or advanced users. It calls back-end to run all possible validations in current component and return resulting errors to display in a dialog. Solves lots of "why can't I do that?".)